# Error :This field must be at most 32 characters long when logging in with facebook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am using login with facebook into my applications and making rerequest parameter as true .
Eg $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectUrl, $permissions,true);
When I try to do login, it throws this error.
This field must be at most 32 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this happens when you have the wrong App ID, App Secret or redirect URI.